# Config script passing value to another script

Tags: bash

I got these two scripts, `configScript.sh` and `genScript.sh`. The first one works precisely how I want to. I would like the second one to maintain the the option chosen last time the config file ran, and then display the correct `echo`depending on that. As it is now it always displays the second option. Is this doable?

```
#!/bin/bash -x
func()
{
echo "
Choose
1 - Option 1
2 - Option 2
"
echo -n "   Enter selection: "
read select
case $select in
            1 ) 

            echo "  Option 1 chosen"
            export OPTION=one
            . ./genScript.sh
            ;;
            2 )
            echo "  Option 2 chosen"
            option="two"
            export OPTION=one
            . ./genScript.sh
            ;;
esac
}
clear
func
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
func2()
{
    if [ ${OPTION} == "one" ] ; then
        echo "Option one"
    else  
        echo "Option two"
    fi
}
func2
```

To clarify, if I run `configScript.sh` and choose option it outputs `Option one` as I want. If I then run `genScript.sh` I want it as well to output `Option one`

Edit*
Updated the code

Comment: @janos Can you specify I bit better? Preferably with code examples since I'm very new to bash

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "export option" instead of "export searchBar".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
func()
{
echo "
Choose
1 - Option 1
2 - Option 2
"
echo -n "   Enter selection: "
read select
case $select in
            1 ) 

            echo "  Option 1 chosen"
            OPTION=one
            export OPTION
            ./genScript.sh
            ;;
            2 )
            echo "  Option 2 chosen"
            OPTION=two
            export OPTION
            ./genScript.sh
            ;;
esac
}
clear
func

#!/bin/bash
func2()
{
    if [ ${OPTION} == "one" ] ; then
        echo "Option one"
    else  
        echo "Option two"
    fi
}
func2
```

and finally run the configScript.sh with this command: `. ./configScript.sh` from the shell.

Comment: But this won't solve the fact that I want the updated `genScript.sh` to run if I just write `./genScript.sh` in the shell, am I correct?

Comment: Ok, now I unterstand the actual problem and my answer won't work then.

Comment: I have changed my answer, so that the chosen value should live on after the first script is terminated. I hope it works.

Comment: If I understood you right I should change the lines in `configScript` from `option=one 
export option
./genScript.sh` to `export OPTION=one ./genScript.sh`. If so, I get this error when I run the script `./genScript.sh: line 5: [: =: unary operator expected
`

Comment: Quite strange, I don't get such an error. If the code over two lines worked, you can switch back to it. I forgot to add that you will have to run the first script with `. ./configScript.sh` This means the script will run in the parent shell and set the environmental variables.

Comment: I updated the code to the one I'm running when I get that error. Have I done any errors?

Comment: I can't see any errors. Seems like the export command on your system is slightly different, but the previous way with setting the option varible should also work.

Comment: Try to run your main script (configScript.sh) with `. ./configScript.sh`

Comment: That made it work! Is there anyway to incorporate that into the code so it's not necessary to write `. ./configScript.sh` everytime I want to configure the script?

Comment: I'm also curious whether it is possible to skip the dot. I'm going to post a question and I'll let you know if I get an answer.

Comment: I now noticed that the `genScript.sh` still gives the same error when I run it separately so the problem is not solved.

Comment: This solution only works for the current session. Was it interrupted?

Comment: Changing to `[[ ${OPTION} == "one"]]` solved the error but the `genScript` is still not working as I want it

Comment: I've tested the code from my answer and `genScript` gets the right oprions selected with `configScript`. What's exactly your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you actually have a comment line before your shebang line: `#!` must be the first 2 characters in the file.

I also wonder if you're actually executing these scripts with `sh` instead of `bash`. Change

```
[ "$option" == "one" ]
```

to

```
[[ $option == "one" ]]
```

---

Instead of exporting, the config script needs to store the value:

```
declare -p OPTION > ~/.my_config
```

And then the other script can do

```
. ~/.my_config
if [[ $OPTION == "one" ]]; ...
```

Comment: I changed so the shebang is first. This will still not solve the problem of the `genScript.sh` to keep the value of `option` from the last time I ran `configScript.sh` if I run it separately.

Comment: Oh, that's a completely separate question: you need to store the value of the previous value somewhere permanently, like to a file, and then genscript will have to read that file..